# Formalization of the Proof of the Theorem of the Bijection of Composition of Two Mappings

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm trying to formalize in FOL the proof of the stated theorem.
Assume two mappings $f$,$g$.
With a slight circularity for brevity's sake, let

- $B(f): \text{"f is a mapping which is bijective whose codomain is the domain of g"}$,
- $B(g): \text{"g is a mapping which is bijective whose domain is the codomain of f"}$, and
- $B(g\circ f): \\\text{" $g\circ f$ is a composition which is bijective and whose domain is that of f and codomain that of g"}$

Theorem: $\forall f\forall g:B(f)\wedge B(g)\rightarrow B(g\circ f)$

Let $X:=dom(f), Y:=codom(f)=dom(g), Z:=codom(g)$.
We prove with

- $I(f): \text{"f is injective"}$
- $S(f): \text{"f is surjective"}$

that the inverse image is unique via injectivity of $f$ and $g$ (conjoined uniqueness of the inverse images if unique images), and via surjectivity of the both
$$
S(g)\leftrightarrow\forall z\in Z\exists y\in Y:g(y)=z
$$
that 
$$
S(g)\wedge S(f)\longrightarrow (g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))=g(y)=z,
$$
unquantified, as taken over from a common verbal proof.
Now we substitute
$$
\forall g(\forall z(\exists y:g(y)=z)\wedge\forall f(\forall y(\exists x:f(x)=y))\longrightarrow \forall z\exists y\exists x: g(y)=z\wedge f(x)=y.
$$

**What I can't explain** but what seems correct from the standpoint of the verbal proof and the conclusion that it reasonably draws, is whether this transition from the conjunction $$\forall z\exists y:P(y,z)\wedge\forall y\exists x P(x,y)$$ to $$\forall z\exists y\exists z:P(y,z)\wedge P(x,y)$$ is valid. **And whether this is an implication or indeed an equivalence.**

I am slightly familiar with the propositional logic and the quantification theory  but have no knowledge of the formal proof theory nor model theory. I will gratefully acknowledge all answers regardless of the complexity, as I'm eager to learn. Especially I'll be grateful for any answer that would also draw a link to the particular concept in proof or model theory, as I'm trying to systematize this (plain keywords good enough--just to learn what to look for).

Comment: I guess you mean $\forall f\forall g\colon ((B(f)\land B(g)\to B(g\circ f))$ for your Theorem

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks.